# Get django to check current URL and if contains a particular string, to add in a class

Tags: html, django

Is there a way out there for Django to check a url and if it contains a given path to then add in a class to a particular item?

Right now this is what I've got and I think I'm confused as to what step would be next.

1. Tried to follow the tutorial on http://gnuvince.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-django-template-tag-for-the-current-active-page/#comment-290. I got to the point where I've created a tags.py file and I've loaded that into the HTML file using the {% load tags %} (which works fine). Now I'm just stuck on what I can do to add some tags into the class="{% like an if tag comparing something%}CLASS TO ADD HERE {% endiftag comparing%}".

Let me know if this makes sense or if more classification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**page.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% load utility %}

 {% block content %}
 <ul class="big-menu">
     <li>
         <a href="{% url main:home %}" class="{% ifpathmatch "main:home" %}current{% endifpathmatch %}">Home</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
 {% endblock %}
```

(template_tags)
**utility.py**

```
 import re

 from django import template
 from django.core.urlresolvers import NoReverseMatch
 from django.templatetags.future import url as django_url_func

 register = template.Library()


 def ifurlmatch(parser, token):
     """
     This is a block tag similar to an {% if %}{% endif %} block.

     It will conditionally display the content between matching
     {% ifurlmatch %}{% endifurlmatch %} tags if the URL path (minus hostname)
     matches the parameter, which should be a string or regex pattern.
     """
     tag_name, pattern = token.split_contents()

     # Arg, split_contents doesn't remove encapsing quotes.
     pattern = pattern.strip('"\'')
     nodelist = parser.parse(('endifurlmatch'))
     parser.delete_first_token()
     return UrlMatchNode(nodelist, pattern)


 class UrlMatchNode(template.Node):
     def __init__(self, nodelist, pattern):
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.nodelist = nodelist

     def render(self, context):
        if self._path_matches(context):
            return self.nodelist.render(context)
        return ''

     def _path_matches(self, context):
        req = context['request']
        path = req.META.get('PATH_INFO', '/')
        return re.search(self.pattern, path) is not None

 register.tag("ifurlmatch", ifurlmatch)


def ifpathmatch(parser, token):
    """
    This is a block tag similar to an {% if %}{% endif %} block.
    It will conditionally display the content between matching
    {% ifpathmatch %}{% endifpathmatch %} tags if the current page's URL
    matches the named path from v1.py passed in as the parameters.

    BUG/NOTE: Currently all string parameters to this must be quoted, or it
    will never match. For example, to match the
    relationships:clients:activity URL path you would need to do the
    following:
        {% ifpathmatch "relationships:clients:activity" "my-client-slug" %}
    Parameters which aren't literal strings shouldn't be quoted.
    For example, if passing in a client object's slug:
        {% ifpathmatch "relationships:clients:activity" myclientobj.slug %}
    """

    nodelist = parser.parse(('endifpathmatch'))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return NamedPathMatchNode(nodelist, parser, token, True)


def ifpathcontains(parser, token):
    """
    Similar to ifpathmatch, but will return true if url contains passed in path
    """
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endifpathcontains'))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return NamedPathMatchNode(nodelist, parser, token, False)


class NamedPathMatchNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, parser, token, strict):
        self.token = token
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.parser = parser
        self.strict = strict

    def render(self, context):
        reversed_url = None
        try:
            reversed_url = django_url_func(
               self.parser, self.token).render(context)
        except NoReverseMatch:
            pass

        if self.strict:
            if reversed_url is not None and self._path_matches(
               context, reversed_url):
               return self.nodelist.render(context)
        else:
            if reversed_url is not None and self._path_contains(
               context, reversed_url):
               return self.nodelist.render(context)
        return ''

    def _path_matches(self, context, reversed_url):
        req = context['request']
        return req.META.get('PATH_INFO', '/') == reversed_url

    def _path_contains(self, context, reversed_url):
        req = context['request']
        return reversed_url in req.META.get('PATH_INFO', '/')

 register.tag("ifpathmatch", ifpathmatch)
 register.tag("ifpathcontains", ifpathcontains)
```